# How to split a certain element in a vector by letters?

Tags: r, vector, split

For example, I have an element "computer" in a vector. I need to get a vector consisting of "c", "o", "m", "p", "u", "t", "e", "r".

And the second part of my question is optional. How can I create a vector containing letter combinations of the elements of the above mentioned vector and letters in the resulting combinations will be only in such order as in the original word? For instance, I want to get something like "puter" or "mpu" in this vector instead of "tumpo".

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
strsplit("computer", "\\b")
```

and

```
library("RWeka")
gsub(" ", "", 
     NGramTokenizer(paste(strsplit("computer", "\\b")[[1]], collapse=" "), 
                    Weka_control(min=2, 
                                 max=5)),
     fixed=TRUE)  
# [1] "compu" "omput" "mpute" "puter" "comp" 
# [6] "ompu"  "mput"  "pute"  "uter"  "com"  
# [11] "omp"   "mpu"   "put"   "ute"   "ter"  
# [16] "co"     "om"    "mp"    "pu"    "ut"   
# [21] "te"    "er"
```

to create n-grams with 2 <= n <=5.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the question is really easy to get:

```
splits <- unlist(strsplit("computer",split=""))

> splits
[1] "c" "o" "m" "p" "u" "t" "e" "r"
```

For the second part you can use the following code:

```
subseqs <- 
  unlist(
    lapply(1:length(splits),FUN=function(x){
      lapply(1:(length(splits)+1-x),FUN=function(y){ 
        paste(splits[y:(y+x-1)],collapse="") })
    })
  )
> subseqs
 [1] "c"        "o"        "m"        "p"        "u"        "t"        "e"       
 [8] "r"        "co"       "om"       "mp"       "pu"       "ut"       "te"      
[15] "er"       "com"      "omp"      "mpu"      "put"      "ute"      "ter"     
[22] "comp"     "ompu"     "mput"     "pute"     "uter"     "compu"    "omput"   
[29] "mpute"    "puter"    "comput"   "ompute"   "mputer"   "compute"  "omputer" 
[36] "computer"
```

Answer (score 0):

For three consecutive letter combinations:

```
x <- strsplit("computer", "\\b")
y <- combn(seq(x),3); m <- match(1:6,y[1,])
combn (x,3)[,m]
```

[image]